# Calculate number of function calls for any size N

Tags: python, algorithm, analysis

I'm trying to understand a way to write how many times the print statement for fun1 will be called for any size N. Written in summation form. This is more of an analysis question. I know I could just setup a count variable and print the result. S is an array of N items. N is the size.

```
def myAlg(S,n):
    for i in range(1,n+1):
        for j in range(1,i+1):
            for k in range(1,j+1):
                if j > k:
                    print('fun1 called, and count is now', count)
                else:
                    print('fun2 called')
```

Im honestly a little lost on how to approach this. Any explanation would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

For two first loops we have sum of arithmetic progression `1+2+3+...+n`, and result is

```
T(n) = n*(n+1)/2
```

known as trianglular numbers (1,3,6,10,15,21...)

So loop for `k` is executed `T(n)` times, and inner part is executed

```
Q(n) = sum(T(i),i=1..n) = n*(n+1)*(n+2)/6
```

times, sequence is known as tetrahedral numbers (1,4,10,20,35,56...)

But we have to subtract `T(n)` to exclude `fun2` calls (one per loop)

```
Result = n*(n+1)*(n+2)/6 - n*(n+1)/2 = (n-1)*n*(n+1)/6
```

This is the same `Q` sequence without the last term, so

```
Result(n) = Q(n-1) = (n-1)*n*(n+1)/6
```

Comment: @BeanBop Is my answer unclear?